# Iterated function in differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, iterated-function-system

I am currently working on a problem that involves differential equations that contains iterated functions. The problem can be described as that one seeks the solution for the equation

$$
\dot{x} = f^{n}(x)
$$

where the right-hand side is an iterated function. A simple example can be the equation

$$
\dot{x} = \textrm{sin}(\textrm{sin}(x))
$$
with $f = \textrm{sin}(x)$ and $n = 2$.

My issue is that I could not find any materials on these types of equations, because I am not even sure what they are called. As such the question is if there is any proper material on this topic that might contain solution methods or some general theorems. I am using these iterated functions in adaptive control and they seem to be very effective in treating parametric disturbances of nonlinear systems which makes them interesting to analyze.

Comment: They are called *untractable* ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of your equation, which is separable, is "simply"

$$x(t)=x_0+F^{-1}(t-t_0)$$ where $F$ is the antiderivative of $\dfrac1{f_n}$.

I don't think that you will find much theory specific to this particular kind of equation (unless they are frequent in your application domain). I would have a look at the properties of iterated functions in general.